# Can't understand the reason for a piece of Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the default layout of application.html.erb that gets generated the book has added this line of code, saying because rails loads all of the stylesheets at once, we need a convention to limit controller-specific rules to pages associated with that controller. Using the controller_name as a class name is an easy way to do that..and they have added this code:

```
<body class = '<%= controller.controller_name %>' >
```

But still I don't understand what is it doing?  Can someone explain it ? and actually is it a common and recommended thing to do or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a way to scope your css based on the controller.

Let's say you have 2 models: `Car` and `Brand`, and you want the top menu to be green on the page where you display all the cars, and red on the page where you display the brands.

On the page where you list all the cars (cars#index), the body would look like that:

```
<body class="cars">
```

On the page where you list all the brands (brands#index), the body would look like that:

```
<body class="brands">
```

So you would be able to write your css like the following:

```
.cars .menu {
    background: green;
}

.brands .menu {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically setting the `class` of the body to the current controller name. So if you have a layout that's shared between multiple controllers, you will have a different class for the body depending on the controller that is currently active. This lets you scope the CSS depending on the controller. For example in SCSS:

```
body.auth {
    background-color: red;
    .row {
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
}

body.post {
    background-color: green;
    .row {
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
}
```

With this, when you are in any of the `AuthController` actions, your site's background color will be `red`. When in the `PostController`, it'll be `green`. Notice that the `row` class name is common between the two, but because you are scoped to the controller, they won't compete in the browser.

You can scope all of your CSS styles this way and it helps to almost give a namespace to your CSS styles in case you may have conflicts of class names across the different controllers. Since your CSS is all joined together from the asset pipeline, that could easily cause rendering issues if you have competing class names. This helps alleviate that.

Comment: `controller_name` does not return `auth_controller` for the class `AuthController`, but just `auth`.

Answer (score 1):

It's adding a CSS class to the body with the same name as the controller name. This is useful when targeting a specific controller via CSS to add custom styling for all actions on that controller. So let's say you have an AdminController for your admin section, and you want the page background to be different so you know you're in the Admin section as opposed to the section other users will see.

```
body.admin {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Another convention I've seen to accomplish something similar is to load a CSS file with the name of the current controller:

http://shaunchapman.me/post/446260774/rails-tip-automatically-link-a-controllers-stylesheet

I think both ways are fine as long as you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to add also action_name to body class

```
<body class='<%= "#{controller_name} #{action_name} %>'
```

You may scope not only CSS but also Javascript to controller or action. (becauses .js files as well as .css are merged together by assets pipeline)

CoffeeScript example:

```
$(document).ready ->
  if $('body').hasClass('cars')
    //..code for cars only controller
```

SASS example:

```
.cars {
  .menu { background-color:blue; } # cars controller specific css
  &.new {
    .menu { background-color:red; } # cars' action new specific css
  }
}
```